# Apache-httpd processes die with segmentation fault on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, apache, ruby-enterprise-edition

I'm running Rails 2.3.3 application which is deployed with passenger/mod_rails with ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610 and apache httpd.

The problem is that whenever I deploy our application, hundreds of httpd processes start dying. I'm getting this error:

```
[notice] child pid NNNNN exit signal Segmentation fault(11)
```

After a short period of time 10-20min. those errors pass off.

This problem started after migrating our database to a separate and dedicated machine. So I think it could be a problem of the mysql-db connection pools and management, however I can not define it.

Does anyone could help me with this problem or just give me a clue how to debug it deeper. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by enabling core dumps on your server.

Then run it to get a core file to get a backtrace and get an initial idea of where the server is core dumping.

I'm going throught the same problem at the moment. Not with Rails though.

HTH